# Image getting distorted by parent div

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a div, I am new to html/css, the image is following the proportions of the div it is inside, which is height*width (100%*50%). I realize I can make the image correct by adjusting its height, but that seems a bit forceful.  Im using display flex tags. Could it be that?

```
html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

#parent_div {
display: flex;
flex-direction: right;
height: 100%;
}

#child_div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #F0A537;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#child_div2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #468966;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: use height: auto; for image

Comment: Then it becomes 100% height of the screen. Like the div it is inside

Answer (score 1):

You have set your image as `height:20%`. You need to change the 20% height to `auto`, that way the image will maintain its own proportions. then you set the width in either pixels or percentage to make it fit in your div.